# Difference in translating Sanskrit words कोप​ [kopa] and क्रोध [krodha]

Tags: etymology, semantics, translation, sanskrit, tibetan

Translationg the terms makes a semantic rendering important. [The English resourse](http://sanskritdictionary.com/) translates ***क्रोध [krodha]*** as 'anger' wrath, passion, etc.' with  the same definition for ***कोप​ [kopa]*** plus defining it as 'morbid irritation or disorder of the humors of the body'. The compound noun ***कोपकारण [kopakāraṇa]*** is rendered there as 'cause of anger', by which I deduce that in English translation these two words are mainly synonymous and covered by a same semantic field.

Tibetan language renders both ***क्रोध [krodha]*** and ***कोप​ [kopa]*** as **ཁྲོ་བ་** [khro ba] and **ཁྲོས་པ་** [khros pa] respectively.

The [German resourse](http://spokensanskrit.de/) covers both terms with the word 'wrath' with ***क्रोध [krodha]*** being in some context synonymous to 'passion'. Ah, and ***कोप​ [kopa]***, too.

So my question is, are there any other possible distinction between the meaning of these two words except of possible [structured] ***क्रोध [krodha]*** VS [non-structured] ***कोप​ [kopa]***?

Are these two words cognates?

Answer (score 1):

कोप and क्रोध are **not** cognates (or more accurate, doublets, since they are in the same language). They have different Sanskrit roots (कुप् and क्रुध्) and no proposed common source in Proto-Indo-European.

They at least have a large semantic overlap even if they aren't exactly the same. क्रोध is not uncommon in Hindi as a Sanskrit borrowing (Sanskrit is a superstrate of Hindi), while कोप is rare.

Answer (score 0):

( *Since I am not an expert on Tibetan and German, this answer might be biased to Sanskrit and Hindi but this won't affect the answer asked for* )

I have generally seen *krodha* when there is a negative connotation of anger or when the anger might result in a (mythological) curse and *kopa* when it's godly/well-reasoned/non-cursing anger. AFAIK cognates are a pair of words which are similar semantically and phonetically but are from **2** different languages, but *krodha* and *kopa* are both used simultaneously (at least now) in Sanskrit and Hindi.

P.S. Now though, in Hindi, generally, *kopa* is used to refer it's religious nature and *krodha* is used in almost every sense.